# Mysql database join query from tables based on user login

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have 2 mysql tables - `websites` and `files`. I am expecting the end result table to show me all the website id's for each user logged in and to show the correct filename against them.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT w1.websites_id ,w1.name ,f1.file_name ,f1.user_id
FROM websites w1 
LEFT JOIN files f1 ON f1.websites_id=w1.websites_id
```

My current output is as below

```
websites_id | websites_name |uploaded_user| file_name
----------------------------------------------------
1           | abc.com      | user1        | test.png
2           | 123.com      | user1        | start.png
2           | 123.com      | user2        | fast.png4
----------------------------------------------------
```

Website1 (abc.com) for user 2 need to show up in my end table but not able to get that

```
-----------------------------
Websites_id | websites_name |
1           | abc.com       |
2           | 123.com       |
----------------------------

Files Table
-----------------------------
Files_name | websites_id  | uploaded_user|
------------------------------------------
test.png   |  1            | user1
start.png  |  2            | user1
fast.png    | 2            |  user2
------------------------------------------
```

I need expected  output as

```
websites_id | websites_name |uploaded_user| file_name
----------------------------------------------------
1           | abc.com      | user1        | test.png
2           | 123.com      | user1        | start.png
1           | abc.com      | user2        | null
2           | 123.com      | user2        | fast.png
1           | abc.com      | user3        | null
2           | 123.com      | user3        | null
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? "I need" is not a question or a problem statement.

Comment: P.s. I suggest you start by studying JOIN queries from a tutorial

Comment: I have edited with where i have struck, what i have tried, please check it once

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running like this by using INNER JOIN Query

select w1.websites_id ,w1.name ,f1.file_name ,f1.user_id
from websites w1
INNER JOIN files f1 ON f1.websites_id=w1.websites_id